# Scrolling bug in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I've been working on an overlay menu recently. It'll contain a long list of names (can't be avoided). It behaves perfectly on Chrome, but the list refuses to scroll on Firefox. I've no idea what's causing this but have created a JSFiddle to show what's happening.

Link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1t0awp8r/3/)

A bit of the HTML:

```
<div class="full-menu">
  <div class="full-menu--middle">
    <button class="menu-toggle menu-toggle--close"></button>    
    <div class="section group menu_items">
        <ul>
            <li>a bunch of options vvv</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A bit of the CSS:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


.main_menu {
    display: none;
}

.full-menu {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: table;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}

.full-menu--open {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.full-menu--middle {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.menu-toggle {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}

.menu-toggle:before {
    content: '\f0c9';
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.menu-toggle--close {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}

.menu-toggle_black {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    color: #000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}

.menu-toggle_black:before {
    content: '\f0c9';
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.menu_items{
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}

.page_inner_ {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.page_container {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: I see the exact same behaviour on FF and Chrome. I am using a Mac. Make sure your FF is up to date

Comment: Hey,

I've run on the most up to date version and have a friend test for me. The exact issue is that if you open the fiddle and click the icon to open the menu, the list will scroll on Chrome, but not on Firefox. I've not found any way to get it to scroll on FF. Which version are you running? I'm also on OS X and have had no luck across multiple devices unfortunately

Comment: Check your console for errors, I get `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href*=#]:not([href=#])` in FF. I don't even see any anchors in the code. Oh nvm the list scrolling, yea you have it as position `fixed` so it won't scroll, change to `absolute`

Comment: Oops, that's a bit left over from the actual site. The <li> elements are a href="#" anchors, I've left it in the fiddle. If you mean .full-menu, changing it to absolute means that it scrolls out of the viewport when at the bottom of the list unfortunately. Main issue I have is that it works perfectly on Chrome, just not FF :/

Comment: You can use `overflow-y: scroll` to make the menu div scroll however you need to make some updates to the `display` and may require other changes on your setup. I am not sure why you need to use table display for it but that's the option. I am not sure what is the desired outcome of this thing is

Comment: With a bunch of hacking about and repurposing I got this to work by changing the display property and some other bits. Thanks for your time and patience, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Take `display:table;` off of `.full-menu` and take `display:table-cell;` off of `.full-menu--middle` then add `overflow:scroll;` to `.full-menu`.

Comment: I've tried, but the menu will scroll and disappear while the background content scrolls which is part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should give `position: absolute;` to `.full-menu`, instead of `fixed`.

Comment: The issue with that is that the list will scroll and disappear while you continue to scroll down to view the content behind

Answer (score 0):

How to Fix Overflow Issues in CSS Flex Layouts:

"... add min-height: 0; to the flex child that has our overflow container ..."

https://moduscreate.com/blog/how-to-fix-overflow-issues-in-css-flex-layouts/